# Is this question about orbit arc length and elliptic integrals on-topic, or is there a form of it that would be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I found summat and would like to share it, so others may avoid the waste of time I spent sorting it out.

See [broken link here](https://github.com/drbitboy/ValladoAlfano2014/blob/tmp/ssb.txt) and [broken link here (see comment below)](https://github.com/drbitboy/ValladoAlfano2014/blob/tmp/ssb_background.png).

Is that on-topic?  I have a feeling it is too much like a discussion or poll question, even though I try to avoid that.

Could I instead make it a question specifically about the topic (e.g. how do I calculate arc length along an orbital path?) that I answer myself?

Thanks.

Comment: Both of the links are broken/404s, FYI

Comment: Thanks for the poke.  Yes, I took this to the SE-meta chat and someone (TidalWave?  Thanks to whoever it was) considered it an opinion poll, so I deleted that branch.  The master branch is [here](https://github.com/drbitboy/ValladoAlfano2014/)